# How can I access the super of the super class in JS?

Tags: javascript, class, object, dom-events

The code is pretty explanatory. What I am doing is wrong. How can I access the a property of the A object in the `onclick` event of an object declared inside of an `A` object method?

```
function A(){
    this.a = 0;
};

A.prototype.myfun= function(){
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName("myclassName");
    b[0].onclick = function(e){
    //How can I get the a property of the A object in here?
        this.a = 1;
    }
};
```

Could I somehow pass this as an argument like this?

```
b[0].onclick = function(e, this){
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing class member variables inside an event handler in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076010/accessing-class-member-variables-inside-an-event-handler-in-javascript) and [Preserve 'this' reference in javascript prototype event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8100469/218196) and [How can I access `this` in an event handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7696672/218196).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `this` in a function references to the function itself, you could do 2 things. Pass around the reference, or create a variable you won't overwrite that represents the `this`

```
function A(){
    this.a = 0;
};

A.prototype.myfun= function(){
    var self = this;
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName("myclassName");
    b[0].onclick = function(e){
        self.a = 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: this is absolutely amazing!